# Get previous score of user x

Tags: google-sheets, count, sum, google-sheets-formula, countif

Consider the following data set:

```
     A:User  |  B:Date     | C:Score  | D:DiffLastResult
1:   John      2021-01-01     7
2:   Jane      2021-01-01     7
3:   James     2021-01-01     8

4:   John      2022-01-01     4
5:   Jane      2022-01-01     9
6:   James     2022-01-01    10

7:   John      2022-06-01    10
8:   Jane      2022-06-01     5
9:   James     2022-06-01     7
```

Now, I want in column D to have the abs difference between the current score and the previous score (for the given user). So, for instance, user James' last score is 7. Previous score of James was 10, so the delta is minus 3, which should be displayed in cell D9. In cell D6, I want to have a value of 2 (10-8, previous score of James, in context of the score of 2022-01-01).

This list is simplified, for the purpose of asking this question. In my real file, the list of names is unorderded, non-repetitive (not all users have the same amount of scores)

I am using Google Sheets. I have tried using vlookup, lookup, and index/match combinations, but I keep getting the first score of James (instead of the previous one). The list is sorted on date ASC.

Can somebody point me in the right direction? Many thanks.

Comment: so you want -3 or 2 ??

Comment: For each row, I want to have the difference with the previous score for the given user. So, in my example above, i want in D9 the value of -3, and in D6 the value of 2.

Comment: Well, the most beautiful would be if date is accounted in calculation. But, like I said, the list is supposed to be sorted on date, so it can be accomplished on row basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(
 A1:A&COUNTIFS(A1:A, A1:A, ROW(A1:A), "<="&ROW(A1:A))-1, {
 A1:A&COUNTIFS(A1:A, A1:A, ROW(A1:A), "<="&ROW(A1:A)), C1:C}, 2, )))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I replicated the layout of your Sheet and used the formula, but I get an error on the VLOOKUP (out of range). See https://ibb.co/Hz5QWjQ for screenshot.

Comment: @RayK change `;C1:C` to `\C1:C`

Comment: Thanks, it works. Awesome! I don't fully understand the syntax here. Now I got the previous score. How can I substract that from the value in cell C (same row)? I tried just to add C1 - ARRAYFORMULA(....) but that doesn't work. Also, within the parameter of ARRAYFORMULA(). How can I use the value in the same formula?

Comment: YES! I just figured it out! Thanks for the confirmation.